# Piecewise equations for spline

Tags: matlab

I have a set of data and i want to use curve fit toolbox in matlab to plot a spline graph for the data. i have done this:

```
x =

  Columns 1 through 10

     0    1.2500    1.8800    2.5000    5.0000    6.2500    6.8800    7.1900    7.5000   10.0000

  Columns 11 through 13

   12.5000   15.0000   20.0000
y =

  Columns 1 through 10

      -85.9300  -78.8200  -56.9500  -34.5600  -33.5700  -39.6400  -41.9600  -49.2800  -66.6000  -66.6100

      Columns 11 through 13

      -59.1600  -48.7800  -41.5300
    cftool
 [breaks,coefs,l,k,d] = unmkpp(pp)

breaks =

  Columns 1 through 10

         0    1.2500    1.8800    2.5000    5.0000    6.2500    6.8800    7.1900    7.5000   10.0000

  Columns 11 through 13

   12.5000   15.0000   20.0000


coefs =

   -4.8535   30.6309  -25.0170  -85.9300
   -4.8535   12.4304   28.8095  -78.8200
  -11.9651    3.2573   38.6927  -56.9500
    3.0330  -18.9977   28.9337  -34.5600
   -0.2294    3.7501   -9.1852  -33.5700
  -11.6351    2.8899   -0.8852  -39.6400
  -68.6157  -19.1004  -11.0978  -41.9600
  130.6350  -82.9130  -42.7220  -49.2800
   -6.3971   38.5776  -56.4659  -66.6000
    1.6010   -9.4008   16.4760  -66.6100
   -0.2967    2.6064   -0.5099  -59.1600
   -0.2967    0.3814    6.9597  -48.7800


l =

    12


k =

     4


d =

     1
```

Correct me if i am wrong, is the command `[breaks,coefs,l,k,d] = unmkpp(pp)` able to help me get piecewise equations from the spline graph i obtained? If so, can i know how do i understand the command, so i can use to my own advantage and the significance of the values in coefs, k, d. Thanks! Basically i want to be able to obtain an equation/equations to describe the spline graph i obtained through the curve fit toolbox. any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/unmkpp.html

Comment: In general, if you want to learn about a command try using the help or doc, for example: `help unmkpp` or `doc unmkpp`. You can of course use google, but this will guarantee that the documentation matches your version of Matlab.

Comment: @am304 Thanks.i did came across that page.its just too difficult/abstract for me.

Answer (score 3):

This tries to explain how you can pick apart and display splines generated in Matlab.

Generate mock data

```
xx = [1:10];
yy = cos(xx);
```

Fit the data with a cubic spline

```
pp = spline(xx,yy);
```

Interpolate with the piecewise polynomial, evaluating it over a finer grid in x

```
xxf = linspace(min(xx),max(xx),100);
yyf=ppval(pp,xxf);
```

Start by inspecting `pp`, which contains all of the information about the piecewise polynomial:

```
 pp = 

   form: 'pp'
 breaks: [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
  coefs: [9x4 double]
 pieces: 9
  order: 4
    dim: 1
```

The function

```
[breaks,coefs,l,k,d] = unmkpp(pp)
```

merely unwraps the contents of structure `pp`, such that:

```
 d = pp.dim; 
 l = pp.pieces; 
 breaks = pp.breaks; 
 coefs = pp.coefs;
 k = pp.order;
```

Therefore it isn't necessary to call `unmkpp` if `pp` is a structure containing all of the info (as above), and you just want the coefficients and the breaks. Instead you can just type

```
 breaks = pp.breaks; 
 coefs = pp.coefs;
```

and continue working with this information, as shown below.

Note that for a cubic spline, the order of the polynomials is 4, since the polynomials have the form

> C(1)*X^(K-1) + C(2)*X^(K-2) + ... + C(K-1)*X + C(K)

with K = 4, and therefore each polynomial has *4* coefficients C. The highest order term X^3 is consistent with the spline being *cubic*.

To evaluate the piecewise polynomials:

(1) choose the piece over which you want to evaluate
the polynomial, defined by `breaks`

(2) pick the correct coefficients for that piece, stored in `coefs`.

Because these are piecewise polynomials, we evaluate them over the
range 0-1 and then *stretch* and *shift* them according to the actual value 
of x. We use the range 0-1 to evaluate the polynomial coefficients for the selected piece using the standard function `polyval` to evaluate a polynomial with known coefficients over a range of interest.

So we find the coefficients `cf` corresponding to the piece and evaluate the polynomial at points `xev`:

```
xev = linspace(0,1,100);
cf = pp.coefs(1,:);  
yyp=polyval(cf,xev);
```

We keep some additional info for plotting:

```
br = pp.breaks(1:2); % find the breaks (beginning and end of stretch of interest)
xxp = linspace(br(1),br(2),100);
```

We can generalize this procedure. Thus for the nth piece (say #6):

```
n = 6;

cf = pp.coefs(n,:);
yyp2=polyval(cf,xev);

br = pp.breaks(n:n+1);
xxp2 = linspace(br(1),br(2),100);
```

Of course you can skip the above and just use `ppval` (a function *dedicated* to work with the `spline` family of functions), which will do the
same for you, say for the 3rd piece:

```
br = pp.breaks(3:4); % limits of the piece
xxp3 = linspace(br(1),br(2),100);
yyp3=ppval(pp,xxp3);
```

Finally we `plot` all of the polynomials evaluated above

```
plot(xx,yy,'.')
hold on
plot(xxf,ppval(pp,xxf),'k:')
plot(xxp,yyp,'g-','linewidth',2)
plot(xxp2,yyp2,'r-','linewidth',2)    % <-- generated with polyval
plot(xxp3,yyp3,'c-','linewidth',2)    % <-- generated with ppval
axis tight
```

[image]

Comment: thanks try hard..i am still trying to digest this.cause i am a beginner in matlab. Anyway could i ask if there's any difference between cubic spline and the smoothing spline option in curvefit toolbox?

Comment: @BenjaminAlonsoTan A smoothing spline is used to "reduce" noise, assuming a piecewise polynomial is an accurate way of modeling the underlying signal. That is not the same as generally using a spline to model data (say for the purpose of interpolation). My answer is that those are two different applications and the results would not necessarily be the same