# How to show equation in Matlab fitting toolbox?

Tags: matlab, regression, curve-fitting, spline

I am using matlab curve fitting toolbox to fit a curve to my data. I've used cubic spline, in the plot it's fitting well, but I would like to see the equation used. Is there a way to do that?

Also, is there a way to show the code? I mean the code was used to fit the curve by the toolbox?

Edit: I was able to get the code as the following, file->generate code. 
But still I need to find the equation, can anyone please tell me how I can do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to display any equations on the graph, but you should be able to replicate the cubic spline interpolation using the commands [spline](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spline.html) and [unmkpp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unmkpp.html).

```
% returns the piecewise polynomial form of the cubic spline interpolant
pp = spline(x,Y)
% use unmkpp(pp) to get the piecewise polynomial details
[breaks,coefs,l,k,d] = unmkpp(pp)
```

Note that you will have a set of coefficients for each piece in the piecewise polynomial. For example:

```
x = -4:4;
y = [0 .15 1.12 2.36 2.36 1.46 .49 .06 0];
% cs stores the piecewise polynomial
cs = spline(x,[0 y 0]);
% extract the coefficients
[breaks,coefs,l,k,d] = unmkpp(cs)
% the endpoints of each of the polynomial pieces
breaks =
  -4  -3  -2  -1   0   1   2   3   4
% 8 sets of coefficients (each set of 4 coefficients for one polynomial piece)
coefs =
   0.20344  -0.05344   0.00000   0.00000
  -0.09033   0.55689   0.50344   0.15000
  -0.39211   0.28589   1.34622   1.12000
   0.14878  -0.89045   0.74167   2.36000
   0.13699  -0.44411  -0.59289   2.36000
   0.13325  -0.03313  -1.07012   1.46000
  -0.05998   0.36661  -0.73663   0.49000
  -0.06334   0.18668  -0.18334   0.06000
% the number of pieces is 8
l =  8
% order is 4 (so 4 coefficients)
k =  4
d =  1
% plot the interpolation
xx = linspace(-4,4,101);
plot(x,y,'o',xx,ppval(cs,xx),'-');
```

Comment: Thank you, I did this in the command window, and this is how it worked, pp= spline (Depth, CNCF)

pp = 

      form: 'pp'
    breaks: [1x4427 double]
     coefs: [4426x4 double]
    pieces: 4426
     order: 4
       dim: 1 It seems that these are info about the data, but how to get the equation? I added this line, [breaks,coefs,l,k,d] = unmkpp(pp), but I get many rows of data, each contains 11 values are these the coefficients?

Comment: You have 4426 seperate polynomial pieces. Each piece is a cubic polynomial with 4 corresponding coefficients. There is not one equation: you have 4426 separate equations which are segmented together. This is why your fit looks so smooth; each polynomial piece is only fitting a very small segment of your data!

Comment: Thanks a lot it's a great explanation, but can you please help me in this, I am not sure how to interpret the coefficients. Is it intersection, x^1, x^2, x^3 from right to left? Thank you.

Comment: @Dania You might want to investigate the `spap2` command which allows least-squares spline approximation. For example, you could call `spl2 = spap2(4, 4, x, y)` which creates a cubic spline with just 4 pieces. This won't fit as well as 4426 separate pieces, but it will generalize far better and probably get you closer to what you are looking for.

Comment: @Dania In order to understand how Matlab applies the cubic splines, please see this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18982222/1911540 It's a bit involved.

Comment: Thanks, I write this, spline= spap2 (4,4,Depth, CNCF), but I get 7 different coefs, [20.2245 4.2883 17.9042 15.6914 18.6387 21.2175 0.2035], how to interpret these, since I'm supposed to have only 4 xs and 4 coefficients?

Comment: @Dania The `spap2` command outputs a different form of spline called a `B-form` spline. You can convert it back to `pp` form (piecewise polynomial) using the command `fn2fm`. For example, `ppForm = fn2fm(spline, 'pp')` which I believe should give you the 4x4=16 coefficients expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I only got the breaks, no parameters were given, this is what I wrote, ppform = fn2fm (spline, 'pp')
I got this, 
ppform = 

      form: 'pp'
    breaks: [0 737.6667 1.1065e+03 1.4753e+03 2213]
     coefs: [4x4 double]
    pieces: 4
     order: 4
       dim: 1

Comment: @Dania It looks like it worked. The `breaks` array contains the endpoints of the 4 different polynomial segments (eg, 0-738, 738-1107, 1107-1475, 1475-2213). The `coefs` matrix contains the 4 cubic polynomial coefficients for each of those segment. If you wish to perform interpolations outside of Matlab, you will still need to apply the math according to the instructions in that other SO post I previously referenced.